# SSl over Informix JDBC doesn't work under JBOSS 7

Tags: java, ssl, jdbc, jboss, informix

I want to use my Informix JDBC application over SSL. The DBMS is Informix IBM 11.70.

I'm using a spring-config.xml file in which I declare the datasource bean:

```
<!-- Data source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.sopra.datasource.CustomDataSource" init-method="init"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="url" value="${url}" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
</bean>
```

The problem is that when I deploy my application in Tomcat 7 everything goes well (both TCP and SSL mode), however, when I deploy it in JBOSS 7.1 the SSL connexion mode to the Informix database doesn't work!

When it comes to debugging, the only information that I have is the following :

**Application side:**

```
Caused by: com.informix.asf.IfxASFException: Attempt to connect to database server (my_server_ssl) failed.
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getLocIfxASFException(IfxErrMsg.java:751) [jdbc-4.10.7.20160517.jar:4.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.informix.asf.Connection.openSocket(Connection.java:1864) [jdbc-4.10.7.20160517.jar:4.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.informix.asf.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:427) [jdbc-4.10.7.20160517.jar:4.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.<init>(IfxSqliConnect.java:1416) [jdbc-4.10.7.20160517.jar:4.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.informix.asf.Connection.getEnabledSSLProtocols(Connection.java:2242) [jdbc-4.10.7.20160517.jar:4.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.informix.asf.Connection.openSocket(Connection.java:1805) [jdbc-4.10.7.20160517.jar:4.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    ... 49 more
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to a defect in the 4.10.7 version of the driver.  Try upgrading to either 4.10.8 or 4.10.9 versions. They can be found via maven or through your IBM download site.

**Gradle**

```
compile group: 'com.ibm.informix', name: 'jdbc', version: '4.10.9'
```

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
<artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
<version>4.10.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Brian Hughes!